# Regex to fetch string until the occurrence of a special character in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string which looks like below

```
str = "I have candy='4' and ice cream = 'vanilla'"
```

I want to get terms to the left side of latest `=` and the terms should be fetched until the occurrence of another `=`.

So my string should be

```
leftOfEqual = "'4' and ice cream"
```

Another example

```
str = "I have candy='4' and ice cream = 'vanilla' and house='big'"

leftOfEqual = "'vanilla' and house"
```

This is my `regex` currently

```
leftOfEqual = str.match(/\S+(?= *=)/)[0]
```

But it looks at the first `=` and gives me only the immediate word to the left.

How can I do this?

**NOTE:** In case there is no presence `=` to the left of latest `=`, I should get the complete string till the beginning then.

Comment: How do we know that we need to include `ice` in `ice cream` which is left of the equals? Is `and` a key word to split by?

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/QyihYP/6) help? Try `.*=(.*)=.*` and use `$1` for replacement.

Comment: @Mandy8055 You should probably add that as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @DaneBrouwer Thanks for the same. I was confirming whether it helped OP or not?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer the idea is anything to the left of last `=` till the occurrence of another `=`, that piece of string should be fetched.

Comment: can't you just use `.split('=')`?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `[^\s=]+\s*=([^\r\n=]+)(?:=[^=\r\n]+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/jfTiqy/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `split` and `slice` to find the second to last split group.
`lastIndexOf` solution, to just search from the back.  Find first `=`, then continue to the next `=`, slice between them.

```js
str = "I have candy='4' and ice cream = 'vanilla'"
console.log(
str.split('=').slice(-2)[0]
)

console.log(
str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('=',x=str.lastIndexOf('=')-1)+1,x<-1?undefined:x)
)

str = "and ice cream = 'vanilla'"
console.log(
str.split('=').slice(-2)[0]
)

console.log(
str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('=',x=str.lastIndexOf('=')-1)+1,x<-1?undefined:x)
)

str = "I have cand'4' and ice cream 'vanilla'"
console.log(
str.split('=').slice(-2)[0]
)

console.log(
str.slice(str.lastIndexOf('=',x=str.lastIndexOf('=')-1)+1,x<-1?undefined:x)
)
```

Comment: this is probably the simplest and superb solution :) Why didn't this cross my mind!

Comment: @JvdV sure I will. I was just testing out the different answers and figuring out which one works the best. Will accept shortly.

Comment: @user120242 this works for all cases I tried so far and this one is simplest too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can probably try:

```
.*=(.*)=.*|(.*)=.*
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`.*`** - Matches everything except a newline before a `=` symbol **greedily**.
>
> **`=`** - Matches `=` literally.
>
> **`=(.*)=`** - Represents a capturing group capturing everything between `=`. You can use multiple symbols if you want by using them as character classes something like `[=%#]`.
>
> **`|(.*)=.*`** - Represents an alternate capturing group representing left hand side of the equal sign in case there is no `=` after the latest `=`.
>
> **`$1$2`** - You can use this as the replacement option for replacing the complete string with the required output.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/QyihYP/9)

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

```js
const regex = /.*=(.*)=.*|(.*)=.*/g;
const str = `"I have candy='4' and ice cream = 'vanilla'"
I have candy='4' and ice cream = 'vanilla' and house='big'
Regex is fun
Regex is beauty =
Regex is awesome = test test test
`;
const subst = `$1$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
// You can use trim if you want to get rid of previous or after spaces.
console.log(result);
```

Comment: you need ^$ if you are trying to match line by line.  that's matching the whole string.  Your regex needs to be adjusted to work with no = (he just added that requirement after you commented your solution I think?).  You can make it work with [^=] matching

Comment: Thanks @user120242 for thes suggestion. But according to me if I use; replace then only the possible match will get  replaced. Please see the sample code snippet which I attached. It is working for the string without = also. Please correct me if I'm wrong in unerstanding your comment.

Comment: Ah, you're using replace.  I misread it.  Works fine

Comment: @Mandy8055 your explanation is great. +1 for this.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately I think you could just use `split` and `reverse` with an extra `trim`:

```js
str = "I have candy='4' and ice cream = 'vanilla' and house='big'"
leftOfEqual = str.split('=').reverse()[1].trim();
console.log(leftOfEqual)
```

---

But must you use `regex` one could use a pattern like:

```
[^=]+(?==[^=]*$)
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MklFI6/2)

- `[^=]+` - Negated equal sign, one or more times
- `(?==[^=]*$)` - Positive lookahead for equal sign followed by negated equal sign zero or more times up to end string ancor.

---

[image]

---

This should also tick:

> *"In case there is no presence = to the left of latest =, I should get the complete string till the beginning then."*

Answer (score 2):

In your current pattern `\S+(?= *=)` you are matching 1+ non whitespace chars and assert what is on the right is an equals sign.

You might also use a capturing group and match the last = at the end of the string.

If there is no group 1 value available, then return the match, matching any char except a newline or `=`. Else return the group 1 value.

```
^(?:.*=([^\r\n=]+)=[^=\r\n]+$|[^\r\n=]+)
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `.*=` Match any char except a newline 0+ times until the last occurrence of `=`
- `[^\s=]+` Match any char except `-` or a whitespace char
- `\s*=\s*` Match `=` between optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\r\n=]+` Match 1+ times any char except `=` or a newline
- `)` Close group 1
- `=[^=\r\n]+$` Match the last `=` at the end of the string.
- `|` Or
- `[^\r\n=]+` Match 1+ times any char except a newline or `=`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3972qc/1)

```js
const pattern = /^(?:.*=([^\r\n=]+)=[^=\r\n]+$|[^\r\n=]+)/;
[
  "I have candy='4' and ice cream = 'vanilla'",
  "I have candy='4' and ice cream = 'vanilla' and house='big'",
  "test test ='test test test'"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern)[1] || s.match(pattern)[0]);
});
```

Comment: @JvdV I saw that in the comments, currently if there is a single `=` it will return the whole value after it. So for `test test ='test test test'` it will return `'test test test'` I can be wrong though, maybe it is not the expected outcome.

Comment: @Thefourthbird this is what I was wondering. It should return `test test` for the third one.

Comment: @JvdV I see that you mean, I think in that case you could use an alternation. I have updated it.

Comment: @SouvikRay I see that you mean, I have added an update.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I see it now. +1 for the detailed explanation of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookaround

```js
const findData = (str) => {
  let data = str.match(/(?<==)([^=]+)(?==[^=]*$)/)
  return data ? data[1].trim() : ''
}

let str1 = "I have candy='4' and ice cream = 'vanilla' and house='big'"
let str2 = "I have candy='4' and ice cream = 'vanilla'"

console.log(findData(str1))
console.log(findData(str2))

// You can use split as well

console.log(str1.split('=').slice(-2)[0].trim())
console.log(str2.split('=').slice(-2)[0].trim())
```

Comment: Just a headsup, but if I'd like to test your regex in the console you'd need to rework your question for it to run properly. Though `split`, as mentioned before, is a good solution nonetheless. +

Comment: @JvdV are you using any browser which doesn't support lookbehind ? seems to work fine for me

Comment: Was talking about the anwer you put down. See what happens if you hit `Run` =).